# When to use logger during Exceptionhandling?

Tags: java, logging, exception

I am newbie at Java and I don't know when to use logger. For example is it logical when I use logger in following example. How to say "Okay I should use logger here". To be clear, I am not asking which logger should I use, but should I use logger at all?

```
 public boolean isValid(Object bean, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        try {
            if (Assert.isNull(bean)) {
                throw new NullPointerException(EXC_MSG_BEAN_NULL);
            }

            String dependentFieldActualValue;
            dependentFieldActualValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, dependentField);
            boolean isActualEqual = stringEquals(dependentFieldValue, dependentFieldActualValue);

            if (isActualEqual == ifInEqualThenValidate) {
                return true; // The condition is not met => Do not validate at all.
            }
            return isTargetValid(bean, ctx); // Perform the actual validation on the target field
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in Exceptions? not. during Exception handling: when you want a log of what went wrong why.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add logging in the `catch` block if you re-throw, because *hopefully* the code catching the re-thrown exception will log it for you, and since you did give the re-thrown exception a reference to the original exception, the later logging will include both.

Comment: but I am telling here I tell bean can not be null, should I write also logger here?`throw new NullPointerException(EXC_MSG_BEAN_NULL);`

Comment: @MertYücel No. Let code that catches the exception log it. Include enough information in the exception to be useful, i.e. relevant parameters and/or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loggers are good practice to use. They are used to find out what went wrong and where without using debugger, or in a production environment. 
For example, when you have a doubt regarding the value that is coming as a parameter in a function and you want to check that the correct value is being passed, you can log that value at debug level so that you can be sure that the correct value is being passed and if not, then you can rectify that.

Comment: that's a nice explanation of what a logger is, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Ok. let me try again. Suppose you're running your code in production and unfortunately, an error arise. Now, you haven't placed logger then, It would be very difficult to know the point at which error came. Now, where to use logger: we place logger when entering into the function, exiting the function, before calling the another function, before returning etc. so as to check till which point the program ran successfully. But we don't need to use it in catch block or before throwing the exception. Hope it helps.

Comment: "Now, you haven't placed logger then, It would be very difficult to know the point at which error came." not really. a stacktrace would point us straight to what we need to know